# Changing Paint Color with Jbuttons

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a Paint drawing program in Java, and I can't figure out how to assign the `JButtons` in the code to change the color.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Paint_program extends JFrame {
public Paint_program() {
    Controlcircle.MoveableMousePanel p = new Controlcircle.MoveableMousePanel();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p);

}

public class Controlcircle extends JFrame {
    JButton RedButton = new JButton("Red");
    JButton GreenButton = new JButton("Green");
    JButton BlueButton = new JButton("Blue");
    JButton EraserButton = new JButton("Eraser");
    JButton ClearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    CirclePanel draw = new CirclePanel();

    public Controlcircle() {
        JPanel Panel = new JPanel();
        Panel.add(RedButton);
        Panel.add(GreenButton);
        Panel.add(BlueButton);
        Panel.add(EraserButton);
        Panel.add(ClearButton);

        this.add(Panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        RedButton.addActionListener(new listener());
        GreenButton.addActionListener(new listener());
        BlueButton.addActionListener(new listener());

    }

    class listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color PColor = Color.BLACK;
            if (e.getSource() == RedButton) {
                PColor = Color.RED;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Paint_program frame = new Paint_program();
        frame.setTitle("Paint Program");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class CirclePanel extends JPanel {
        private int radius = 5;
    }

    static class MoveableMousePanel extends JPanel {

        private int x = 20;
        private int y = 20;

        public MoveableMousePanel() {

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    // Get the new location and repaint the screen
                    x = e.getX();
                    y = e.getY();
                    repaint(x, y, x, y);
                }

                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                }
            });
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawLine(x, y, 4, 4);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

so far I've only tried to get the red button to work trying to use this code

```
class listener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Color PColor = Color.BLACK;
            if (e.getSource() == RedButton) {
                PColor = Color.RED;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }
```

but I haven't had any luck getting it to work

(this is my first post on here so if I made any mistakes with the format please let me know for future questions.)

Comment: 1) Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. 2) Class names SHOULD start with an upper case character. Any text book or tutorial will follow these conventions. Take the time to learn them. 3) You need to save the current color that has been selected so it can be associated with the object you want to paint. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example.

Comment: You need some kind of "model" which can maintain the information about what is to be paint and how it is to be painted

Comment: Take a look at this [simple drawing explanation](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/simple-drawing#readme) on Github.